# Android SearchView doesnt enter onQueryTextChange

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am trying to to implement SearchView with Sherlock Action Bar. I am not able to get the query to enter the onQueryTextChange method. Not sure whats going wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    protected static CharSequence[] _categories = { "Amusement Park",
            "Bird Sanctuary", "Wild Life", "River", "Hill Station", "Temple" };

    protected static boolean[] _selections = new boolean[_categories.length];

    private final String[] places = new String[] { "Mysore", "Bangalore",
            "Mangalore", "Wayanad", "Bandipur National Park", "Chickmaglur",
            "Bandipura", "Coorg", "Kodaikanal", "Hampi", "Ghati Subramanya",
            "Mekedatu", "Muththathhi", "Shivasamudram", "Talakadu",
            "Savana Durga" };

    public SearchView mSearchView;
    private TextView mStatusView;

    private Menu mainMenu = null;

    PlacesListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("Nomad", "onCreate");

        List<Place> thePlaces = new ArrayList<Place>();
        for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
            Place pl = new Place("NO_ID", places[i], "NO_DISTANCE",
                    "NO_CATEGORYICON");
            thePlaces.add(pl);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.place_list);
        adapter = new PlacesListAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_place,
                thePlaces);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaceActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i("Nomad", "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        mainMenu = menu;

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        // Search View
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        setupSearchView(searchItem);

        mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // hide action item
                if (mainMenu != null) {
                    mainMenu.findItem(R.id.action_category).setVisible(false);
                    mainMenu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(false);
                }

            }
        });
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                // re-show the action button
                if (mainMenu != null) {
                    mainMenu.findItem(R.id.action_category).setVisible(true);
                    mainMenu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(true);
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

        Log.i("Nomad", "after setupSearchView()");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Searh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("Nomad", "Click Search");
            break;

        case R.id.action_category:
            showDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.action_sort_alpha_az:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alpha AZ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_sort_alpha_za:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alpha ZA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_sort_dist_nf:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dist NF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_sort_dist_fn:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dist FN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            // return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        // | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange");

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange Empty String");
            listView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextChange " + newText.toString());
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        Log.i("Nomad", "onQueryTextSubmit");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        Log.i("Nomad", "onClose");
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your searchCommand :

```
searchCommand.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```